# Is it possible to create an array list of objects in p5JavaScript?

Tags: arrays, arraylist, charts, var, p5.js

### I'm currently working on a Stacked Bar Chart Demo using p5JavaScript as you can see in the Code Snippet Below.

Basically, I want to have 2 series of data on X&Y Axis :

1) An array of numbers (var)

and

2) An Array-List of variables (var1,var2,var3,...).

The only reference I found for this is the link provided below:
https://sites.google.com/site/processingp5js/data-structures/arraylist

If somebody know how to create a "Class of Objects" or an Array-List please let me know.

---

The Script is shown below :

```js
//REFERENCES:
//   https://sites.google.com/site/processingp5js/data-structures/arraylist

/* Needed Variables Declaration */
var arrayOfMonths = ["dd/mm/yy","dd/mm/yy","dd/mm/yy","dd/mm/yy","dd/mm/yy","dd/mm/yy","dd/mm/yy","dd/mm/yy","dd/mm/yy","dd/mm/yy"];
var arrayOfResponses = ["num","num","num","num","num","num","num"];

/* Calculated Variables */
var numOfMonths = arrayOfMonths.length;
var numOfResponses = arrayOfResponses.length;

/* Variables Declaration */
var canvasWidth = numOfMonths * 100;
var canvasHeight = numOfResponses * 100;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
} 

function draw() {
  background(255); //White Background Color
 chartBase(); //Add X,Y Axis
  addPointers(numOfResponses, numOfMonths); //Add Pointers
  addTextToPointers(); //Add Text to pointers
  //addValues(); //Add the Bars (Values) of the Chart
}

function chartBase(){
  
  /* DRAW X AXIS */
  line(canvasWidth-(canvasWidth-50), canvasHeight-100,
       (canvasWidth-50)+25, canvasHeight-100);
  
  /* DRAW Y AXIS */
 line(canvasHeight-(canvasHeight-100),canvasHeight-(canvasHeight-50)-25,
       canvasHeight-(canvasHeight-100),canvasHeight-50); 
}

function addPointers(numOfResponses, numOfMonths){
  
  var spaceBetweenX = canvasWidth - (canvasWidth-150);
 var spaceBetweenY = canvasHeight- 150;
  
  /* ADD POINTERS TO X AXIS */
  for(var x=0; x<numOfMonths; x++){
    
   ellipse(spaceBetweenX,canvasHeight-100,10,10);
    spaceBetweenX += canvasWidth/numOfMonths;
  }
  
  /* ADD POINTERS TO Y AXIS */
  for(var y=0; y<numOfResponses; y++){
    
   ellipse(canvasWidth-(canvasWidth-100), spaceBetweenY, 10, 10);
    spaceBetweenY -= canvasHeight/numOfResponses;
  }
  
}

function addTextToPointers(){

  var spaceBetweenX = canvasWidth-(canvasWidth-125);
 var spaceBetweenY=(canvasHeight-100)-50;
  textSize(13);
  
  /* ADD TEXT TO X AXIS */
  for(var x=0; x<numOfMonths; x++){
    
   var currentText = arrayOfMonths[x];
    text(currentText, spaceBetweenX, (canvasHeight-75));
    spaceBetweenX+=canvasWidth/numOfMonths;
  }
  
  /* ADD TEXT TO Y AXIS */
  for(var y=0; y<numOfResponses; y++){
  
    var currentText = arrayOfResponses[y];
    text(currentText, (canvasWidth-(canvasWidth-60)), spaceBetweenY);
    spaceBetweenY -= canvasHeight/numOfResponses;
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an array.

Arrays in JavaScript act a lot like the `ArrayList` class in Java or Processing. Their size can change, and you can dynamically add or remove elements from them.

Check out [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for tutorials on arrays in JavaScript, or just google "javascript arrays" for a ton of results.

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou What was the way you found?